# How can i move and click a image and an horizontal scrollbox?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I'm Playing with the samples that comes with the trial version of xe5.

Does anybody know how i can click and scroll a image in a horizontal scrollbox.
I know if you set hittest:=true i have events.
But now i can't scroll when i touch the image.

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You'll need to hook the MouseXXXX events and scroll the image from code.